# pip3 "build" will not install

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pip

when I try to install build with

`sudo pip3 install build`

the following error occurs:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 386, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 760, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 382, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
    prefix=prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 153, in distutils_scheme
    d.parse_config_files()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 406, in parse_config_files
    parser.read(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1091, in _read
    fpname, lineno)
configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from 'setup.cfg' [line 10]: option 'url' in section 'metadata' already exists
```

while installing the collected packages. The install never completes; pip says it was never installed. I would greatly appreciate any help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance anyone else has this problem, I found a temporary fix that will probably make python stop working in a few days.. I went to ln 1088-1090 of /usr/lib/python3.7/configparser.py and replaced that bit about raising an exception after an if statement with

```
                        while (self._strict and
                            (sectname, optname) in elements_added):
                            elements_added.pop()
```

This seemed to have fixed the problem, albeit not in the most pretty method, as installation pf build and use of sdist now works ok.